# Toolbar + кнопки + стрелка "назад" + менюшка в правом углу - как?

Tags: java, android

Не могу найти пример как же создать простую активити с `toolbar` наверху и поместить туда мои кнопки типа обновить, выполнить `http` запрос и еще парочку каких-нибудь.

То есть, не только стандартные кнопки, но и/или кастомные тоже. И кнопка меню в правом углу. И еще стрелка "Назад" в этом же `toolbar`.

Как сделать это?

Comment: скриншот того ,что хотите? Навскидку это называется `ActionBar`, нет?

Comment: @metalurgus, думаю, да. Но, пока не уверен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот простые примеры, сейчас появился отдельный компонент toolbar вместо ActionBarActivity теперь AppCompatActivity. Для дополнительных кнопок

http://habrahabr.ru/post/256643/

http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: вроде бы оно... так это toolbar или actionbar? Мне также может понадобиться менюшка в правом углу.

Comment: В новом API это toolbar в старом Actionbar, с toolbar как по мне намного удобнее работать.

Comment: Для бокового меню в android-studio есть шаблон готовый https://habrastorage.org/files/1b1/cf7/d5c/1b1cf7d5c0dc40cc93bad35cd1674ffe.png

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Answer (score 1):

В инете полно уже готовых решений. Вот статья с хабра:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/256643/
Меню итемы добавляете по той же схеме что и раньше, в работе с ActionBar-ом.